# I can't find a way to provide a "graceful shutdown" in Nest microservices, in particular using NATS

Tags: kubernetes, nestjs, graceful-shutdown

Hello everyone I can't find a way to provide a "graceful shutdown" in Nest microservices, in particular using NATS.

Expected behavior:

1. The application in kubernetes received a 'SIGTERM' signal.
2. stops listening for new incoming requests.
3. service of accepted requests is completed and a response is given.
4. the application closes all connections and shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Kubernetes** spec config to set the graceful shutdown for POD: **terminationGracePeriodSeconds**

Default value of **terminationGracePeriodSeconds** is 30 seconds

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: test
spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: test
                image: ...
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

Read best practise : https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace

Comment: This is not a solution, if the application receives SIGTERM and closes the connections  immeditately without finishing the requests then the clients will receive errors